# C# date time in utc format passing issue

Tags: c#, java, .net, windows

My application can run on any kind of machine having any windows OS. Now it will communicate with server host rest api built in java.

Now i am trying to fetch time in utc format like this

```
Console.WriteLine("utc : " + DateTime.UtcNow);
Console.WriteLine("utc : " + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
Console.WriteLine("normal : " + DateTime.Now);
```

its output is like this -

On window7 machine

```
utc : 03-05-2012 10:48:22
utc : 03-05-2012 10:48:22
normal : 03-05-2012 16:18:22
```

On windows server 2008R2 machine

```
utc : 5/3/2012 10:47:35 AM
utc : 5/3/2012 10:47:35 AM
normal : 5/3/2012 4:17:35 PM
```

Now the on server machine its giving utc time with AM/PM but on window7 machine its giving time without  AM/PM why its like this?

Is there any method which will return same utc time on all kind of Windows OS in same format so java guy will not have any parsing issue?

Thanks

Comment: Good if you could use `ToString("s")` which is essentially `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` format

Comment: I dont know how the other guy is parsing. He asked me to provide only single kind of format. Either with AM/PM or without.

Comment: @sunder we are usualy using for such kind of communications the "Sortable date/time pattern" as V4Vendetta has suggested

Comment: I tried executing same, no luck.

Comment: Yea its giving a same kind of format for both win7 and win2K8R2.

utc : 2012-05-03T11:21:38
utc : 2012-05-03T11:21:38
normal : 2012-05-03T16:51:38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we use ToString("s") which is essentially yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss format it will give you same format on different OS having different culture.

we are usually using this for such kind of communications the "Sortable date/time pattern".

thanks to V4Vendetta and ie for their comments.

It will have other guys reading same post having same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The output format depends on the Culture, not on the OS version. See [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to do with the OS necessarily - it's do with the locale that the code runs under.  Chances are that the machines are set with different locales and that accounts for the difference.

If you need to control the format exactly then you should use a custom format string by manually specifing a format through the `DateTime.String(string format)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) with:

```
DateTime.ToString("format string", IFormatProvider)
```

Example:

```
  DateTime.ToString("dd MM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In the above code, make sure that "format string" is the one expected by Java

Comment: Not specifying a `CultureInfo` to use, will still get you (potentially) different strings.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a specific format that should be used for the date (agreed upon between applications)

C# to serialize date:

```
Console.WriteLine("utc : " + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.UtcNow));
Console.WriteLine("utc : " + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()));
Console.WriteLine("normal : " + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now));
```

Java to parse date:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateToParse);
```

Comment: my friend this string.format also gone return same result in a format thats it.On window7 without AM/PM and on windows server R2 with AM/PM.
Now both machine will same same format but one with AM/PM and another without.

Answer (score 0):

One of the idea is you can send time in milliseconds and convert milliseconds to dateTime at Java end.

Answer (score 0):

The [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library would give you consistent results.